# Using Angular animations directly on the component selector does not affect the content of the component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-animations

I'm trying to make a transition on the hiding of some components. I've got this in my  @Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar-aplication-wrapper',
  templateUrl: './sidebar-aplication-wrapper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar-aplication-wrapper.component.css'],
  animations: [
      trigger(
        'inOutAnimation', 
        [
          transition(
            ':enter', 
            [
              style({  opacity: 0 }),
              animate('1s ease', 
                      style({ opacity: 1 }))
            ]
          ),
          transition(
            ':leave', 
            [
              style({  opacity: 1 }),
              animate('1s ease', 
                      style({  opacity: 0 }))
            ]
          )
        ]
      )
    ]
})
```

and this in the html of the same component:

```
<app-iot-component class="bg-primary " *ngIf="loadedApplication == 'iot'" [@inOutAnimation]></app-iot-component>
<app-issues-component class="bg-primary " *ngIf="loadedApplication == 'issues'" [@inOutAnimation]></app-issues-component>
<app-bookings-component class="bg-primary " *ngIf="loadedApplication == 'booking'" [@inOutAnimation]></app-bookings-component>
```

The problem is that I think the transition is not affecting the content of the components. I know for a fact that if i apply the transition on a normal div, the transition works. Any idea?

Angular version :
11.0.9

Comment: It is applied to them but usually they have `display: inline` so most animations don't have an effect.

Comment: @AviadP. That's the answer. Thank you. If you could answer it, I will gladly accept your answer so others can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is applied to them but usually they have `display: inline` so most animations don't have an effect.

Glad to help :)